# How to save 2 student object getting values from form under one submit button in .net MVC application?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, sql-server-2005

Here is the Code and the Controller code is also there[This is the Model of Entity Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYXmk.png)

`public JsonResult Submit(Student_Information stu)
        {
            db.Student_Information.Add(stu);

```
        db.Student_Information.Add(stu);




        db.SaveChanges();}`
```

Comment: public ActionResult Signup(student student)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StudentsEntities db = new StudentsEntities())
                {
                    db.students.Add(student);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    // TODO: Add insert logic here

                    return RedirectToAction("Signin");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<form action="Submit" method="post">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead class="thead-light">
<tr>
<th colspan="4">Part A  :  Student Information</>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th width="2">Reg No:</th>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="Registration_No" size="30" /></td>
<th width="2">Reg No:</th>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="Registration_No1" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Phone</th>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="Phone" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Email</th>
<th><input class="form-control" type="text" name="Email" size="30" /></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>
<button class="btn btn-info form-control" name="Submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

```
 public JsonResult Submit(Student_Information stu)
    {


        db.Student_Information.Add(stu);



        db.Student_Information.Add(stu);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

}

Comment: This is not Working because ID not be duplicated and in sql there is a unique tuple for every record